# MVC Code First Approach doesn't seed data for the Tables. Do we require to enable migration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

**Table to be Created using the below class..**

```
 public class Country
    {
        [Key]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Country Name")]
        [Required]
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Country Code")]
        [Required]
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    }
```

**DBContext Class Inherited**

```
public class DatabaseContext:DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext() : base("StudentContext")
    {
       Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseRepository());
    }
    public DbSet<Country> Countrys { get; set; }

}
```

**Web.Config** **Conneection String**

```
<add name="StudentContext" connectionString="Server=XXXXXX; Database=StudentDB; User Id=xxxxxxx; password=xxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Class for Overriding the Seed Method**

```
 public class DatabaseRepository :DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>
    {


        protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
        {

            Country _country = new Country();
            _country.CountryName = "India";
            _country.CountryCode = "IN";
            context.Countrys.Add(_country);
            context.SaveChanges();
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

Using MVC Web Application I am trying to List the Country List.
The code is able to create the Database and the table using this approach but the seed method is not being executed.

I did try to go through some of the video available and make changes accordingly but nothing seems to execute the Seed Method.

Comment: Did you have seed method when you run you app at first time? Have you tried DropCreateDatabaseAlways?

Comment: Yes, it had the seed method and the I did tried using DropCreateDatabaseAlways

Comment: Do you really have `DatabaseRepository :DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>`? In this case you have to call `Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseRepository())`

Comment: @RomanKoliada is this what you mean... Have updated..

Comment: No, I suggested to replace `Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>());` with `Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseRepository())` in your DatabaseContext ctor

Comment: @RomanKoliada I did as suggested but still the only table created no seed done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144561/discussion-between-roman-koliada-and-rohit-kumar).

Comment: Are you using .NET Core and Entity Framework Core? If so, there is no API for seeding.

Comment: @RomanKoliada It working fine now, Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @RomanKoliada if you can create any answer I can mark it accepted, sorry for requesting so late.

Answer (score 0):

You also need this attribute:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

like:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int CountryId { get; set; }
```

to auto generate the columns.  See [this for an explanation](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute).

Comment: The Database and table are being created using the approach, the only issue is the table data is not being seeded. Let me give it a try to what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

just Try to set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled  to true in your configuration file constructor , like below example

**My Working code:**

```
internal sealed  class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
    public Configuration()
            {
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            }
     protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
        }
}
```

**Note:** the above code as ran the seed automatically and put the data into the database

**In your case:**

```
 public class DatabaseRepository :DbMigrationsConfiguration<DatabaseContext >
    {

    public  DatabaseRepository()
    {
      AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
      protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {

        Country _country = new Country();
        _country.CountryName = "India";
        _country.CountryCode = "IN";
        context.Countrys.Add(_country);
        context.SaveChanges();
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

And see its works, kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: I do not want to use the default class that's generated when you enable migration if I can utilize DatabaseRepository class of mine to achieve it.

Comment: I did tried as suggested but  it's not seeding the data in tables.

Comment: Ok then fine,now i have one question ,did you set the DB initializer class in context class, Here is the link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx
which tells clearly about that. Hope now surely your problem will be solved  , thanks

Comment: thanks for sharing the link. I have tried try this too. But not aware what's confining to achieve the results. I have been struggling with this since 5days. I am new to MVC. Do we require to use command such as enable migrations, add migration and update database commands? If yes I am able to do so.